# How can I store my ArrayList values to MySQL databases?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have some problem to store arraylist value to mysql database with php. This is some code I have been created.

First, I have some class to store variable its called Constant.java :

```
public class Constant {

    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN = "First";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN = "Second";
    public static final String THIRD_COLUMN = "Third";
    public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN = "Fourth";

}
```

Second, I have been import that class to MainActivity.java like this :

```
import static com.testing.informationsystem.Constant.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static com.testing.informationsystem.Constant.SECOND_COLUMN;
import static com.testing.informationsystem.Constant.THIRD_COLUMN;
import static com.testing.informationsystem.Constant.FOURTH_COLUMN;
```

Third, I store my value to arraylist by this way :

```
        btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
        btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                orderValue = txtOrderValue.getText().toString();
                price = txtPrice.getText().toString();

                valueSpinner = spnProductFocus.getSelectedItem().toString();

                HashMap temp = new HashMap();

                if(orderValue.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    orderValue = "0";
                }

                if(price.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    price = "1000";
                }

                double count = Double.parseDouble(orderValue) + Double.parseDouble(price);
                total = String.valueOf(count);

                if(count.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    count = "0";
                }

                temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, valueSpinner);
                temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, orderValue);
                temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, price);
                temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, total);

                list.add(temp);
           }
        });
```

Okay, now I have arraylist contains value I saved from button. And now I will send it through out HTTPOST to PHP and store it to mysql. This is my code to post it to PHP.

```
void saveOrder(){

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://dcmodular.com/saktisetia/mobile/order.php");
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

       --nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(arraylist));--
        ----this is my problem about how to post it to PHP---

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.d("Value : ", response.toString());
                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                String feedback = EntityUtils.toString(entity).trim();
                Log.d("Feedback : ", feedback);

    }
```

Finally, this is my own php file to store it to mysql databases :

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

--receive arraylist from httppost--

$query = "insert into order(value1) values(value1)";

$execute = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if($execute){
    echo "saved";
}else{
    echo "failed";
}

?>
```

That is my code and my problem how to post that arraylist to PHP. Thank you before for your helping.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpUrlConnection as Http Default client is no longer supported.
Try this

```
 public JSONObject function(String value_to_post, String  value_to_post,....){
        try {


            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("your_database_field", value_to_post);



            Log.d("request", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    your_URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

call this function from your activity

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` variable will hold your posted data.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But, how to pass the arraylist in android class ??

Comment: for each item in ArrayList add their `BasicNameValuePair` instance to `nameValuePairs`

Comment: It's similar to @sanky-jain post.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understood about that code. I don't know where I used that code.

Answer (score 0):

In Android:

```
postParameters.add(new Pair<>("value1", value1.toString()));
```

In Php

```
$str = str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$_POST['value1']);
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
$value1 = preg_split("/[,]+/", $str);
$i=0;
while($i<count($value1){
$query = "insert into order(value1) values(value1)";
}
```

Comment: Is variable 'your_data.toString()' arraylist ??

Comment: "value1" on postParameters is contain all arrayList value

Comment: Sorry, How to I declare postParameters ? What is the data type ?

Comment: nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1", value1.toString()));

Comment: but BasicNameValuePair is depreciated from 5.0

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean about BasicNameValuePair is depreciated from 5.0 ??

Comment: It will never use in future. If you use BasicNameValuePair in android studio you will see some error. It's work properly. But in future it will not work

Comment: Can you explain to me to insert this arraylist values to 4 field in database table `{Firts=value1, Second=value2, Third=value3, Fourth=value4}` ?

Comment: insert into order(value1,value2,value3,value4) values(value1,value2,value3,value4);

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

Answer (score 0):

//You have to something similar.
//This is just an idean as i dont know how you declared temp and arraylist

```
for (int i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {

             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(list.get(i).getkey,list.get(i).getValue));

        }
```

Comment: I declared the arraylist like this : private ArrayList<HashMap> list; and temp like this : HashMap temp = new HashMap();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<NameValuePair>` to send POST request to server.

```
 try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "data1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "data2"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I used that but how to I post values in ArrayList using that `nameValuePairs.add` ??